# How can I use ArrayCollection like feature in ActionScript 3.0 Flash IDE?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I heard that `ArrayCollection` on Flex, so how can I use `ArrayCollection` like feature in ActionScript 3.0 and Flash IDE.

Comment: +1 since it wasn't as straightforward to find the answer as I thought it should be.  It is confusing that Flash and Flex have very different frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent Flash IDE class is `fl.data.DataProvider`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/data/DataProvider.html

> The DataProvider class provides methods and properties that allow you to query and modify the data in any list-based component--for example, in a List, DataGrid, TileList, or ComboBox component.
>
> A data provider is a linear collection of items that serve as a data source--for example, an array. Each item in a data provider is an object or XML object that contains one or more fields of data. You can access the items that are contained in a data provider by index, by using the DataProvider.getItemAt() method.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I didnt get this question, try:

[HTTPService and ArrayCollection in Flash CS4](http://www.jeffguthrie.com/httpservice-and-arraycollection-in-flash-cs4)