# Use ArrayCollection in Flash CS5

Tags: apache-flex, flash, arraycollection

is there any way to use ArrayCollection (from mx.collections.*) in Flash CS3/4/5? How?

Comment: Why would you use ArrayCollection outside a Flex app?
None of the Flash CSx component will be able to use it

Comment: Very intelligent comment, thank you   :-D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use the Flex libs in Flash. For collections in AS3, though, [check out this open source project](http://code.google.com/p/as3-collections/). It rocks.

Comment: It seems ther's a way: http://flashauthoring.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-flex-webservice-component-in.html but I don't know what to import in my particular case.

Comment: Oh, it seems I should import a framework.swc... but it's 1,7Mb... I think I will write a class myself or use what you suggested... that's huge size for a simple thing...

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked before. It seems that there is:

[How can I use ArrayCollection like feature in ActionScript 3.0 Flash IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215528/how-can-i-use-arraycollection-like-feature-in-actionscript-3-0-flash-ide)