# 1046:type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ArrayCollecton

Tags: actionscript-3

In my flash AS3 code it shows the error

> 1046:type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:
>   ArrayCollecton

at following lines.

```
var expenses:ArrayCollection;

var gep:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{voltage1:0 ,current1:0 ,voltage2:0, current2:0, voltage3:0 ,current3:0, voltage4:0 ,current4:0}]);

var pow:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{voltage1:0 ,power1:0 ,voltage2:0 ,power2:0, voltage3:0 ,power3:0, voltage4:0 ,power4:0}]);
```

I have imported following to my code.

```
import fl.controls.Label;

import fl.controls.Button;

import fl.transitions.Tween;

import fl.transitions.easing.*;

import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.net.URLRequest;

import flash.display.Loader;

import flash.events.Event;

import fl.controls.CheckBox;

import fl.controls.RadioButtonGroup;

import flash.events.TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE;
```

I feel like the error is related to importing  array collection.How array colection can be imported .Is it like **import fl.collections.ArrayCollection;**?

Answer (score 1):

ArrayCollection is part of the Flex framework.

You need to include this framework: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=168463

Then import ArrayCollections that way:

```
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
```

Links:

[Use ArrayCollection in Flash CS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333065/use-arraycollection-in-flash-cs5)

[How can I use ArrayCollection like feature in ActionScript 3.0 Flash IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215528/how-can-i-use-arraycollection-like-feature-in-actionscript-3-0-flash-ide)

Comment: I have gone through this link " How can I use ArrayCollection like feature in ActionScript 3.0 Flash IDE?"    .......But how this framework.swc can be created? I there is no such file in my as3 project